# Wagtail - how to get tags to work with `telepath` (tags in streamfield)?

Tags: tags, wagtail, wagtail-streamfield

I can use tags in regular page fields without any issue. When using tags within blocks (within a streamfield), the UI works and the tags are saved BUT the current page tags do not show up when loading the page in the admin. *That's because the current value is not in the template anymore, it's in a JSON loaded via `telepath`.*

I can confirm that the tags are saved and present in the data passed to `initBlockWidget` in the page source but these are ignored. Also, if I used a regular text field instead of the tag-widget, I can see the saved-values in the admin.

This is the code I have (which used to be enough before the refactor with `telepath`).

```
from wagtail.admin.widgets import AdminTagWidget

class TagBlock(TextBlock):
    @cached_property
    def field(self):
        field_kwargs = {"widget": AdminTagWidget()}
        field_kwargs.update(self.field_options)
        return forms.CharField(**field_kwargs)
```

I think the following link is what I need to complete somehow to get it to work: https://docs.wagtail.io/en/stable/reference/streamfield/widget_api.html#form-widget-client-side-api

I've tried with this:

```
class AdminTagWidgetAdapter(WidgetAdapter):
    class Media:
        js = [
            "wagtailadmin/js/vendor/tag-it.js",
            "js/admin/admin-tag-widget-adapter.js",
        ]


register(AdminTagWidgetAdapter(), AdminTagWidget)
```

And under `js/admin/admin-tag-widget-adapter.js`:

```
console.log("adapter"); // this shows up in the console


class BoundWidget { // copied from wagtail source code
    
    constructor(element, name, idForLabel, initialState) {
        var selector = ':input[name="' + name + '"]';
        this.input = element.find(selector).addBack(selector);  // find, including element itself
        this.idForLabel = idForLabel;
        this.setState(initialState);
    }
    getValue() {
        return this.input.val();
    }
    getState() {
        return this.input.val();
    }
    setState(state) {
        this.input.val(state);
    }
    getTextLabel(opts) {
        const val = this.getValue();
        if (typeof val !== 'string') return null;
        const maxLength = opts && opts.maxLength;
        if (maxLength && val.length > maxLength) {
            return val.substring(0, maxLength - 1) + '…';
        }
        return val;
    }
    focus() {
        this.input.focus();
    }
}

// my code here:

class AdminTagWidget {
    constructor(html, idPattern) {
        this.html = html;
        this.idPattern = idPattern;
    }

    boundWidgetClass = BoundWidget;

    render(placeholder, name, id, initialState) {
        console.log("RENDER", placeholder, name, id, initialState); // this does not show

        var html = this.html.replace(/__NAME__/g, name).replace(/__ID__/g, id);
        var idForLabel = this.idPattern.replace(/__ID__/g, id);
        var dom = $(html);
        $(placeholder).replaceWith(dom);
        // eslint-disable-next-line new-cap
        return new this.boundWidgetClass(dom, name, idForLabel, initialState);
    }
}
console.log("here") // does show in the console

// variants I've tried:
//window.telepath.register('wagtail.admin.widgets.tags.AdminTagWidget', AdminTagWidget);
//window.telepath.register('wagtail.widgets.AdminTagWidget', AdminTagWidget);
window.telepath.register('path.where.its.used.AdminTagWidget', AdminTagWidget)
```

The log from my custom render method does not show. It seems that I'm not calling the right path within `window.telepath.register` but I don't know how what the string is supposed to be...

I'm not even sure if this is the right way forward.

---

Notes:

- it works in regular field, the question is about tags in blocks
- I'm using Wagtail version 2.13.2 but I've also tried with 2.15 without any difference.
- In the console, I can log window.telepath and see my custom widget. It's just not "applied" to anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `WidgetAdapter` class needs a `js_constructor` attribute:

```
class AdminTagWidgetAdapter(WidgetAdapter):
    js_constructor = 'myapp.widgets.AdminTagWidget'

    class Media:
        js = [
            "wagtailadmin/js/vendor/tag-it.js",
            "js/admin/admin-tag-widget-adapter.js",
        ]
```

Any string value will work here - it just needs to uniquely identify the class, so it's recommended to use a dotted module-like path to avoid colliding with others. This then matches the string you pass to `window.telepath.register` on the Javascript side:

```
window.telepath.register('myapp.widgets.AdminTagWidget', AdminTagWidget)
```

Comment: Thank you so much. That was right in the middle of the doc !